# Merging Branch Into default In Mercurial Dropping All default Changes

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I branched from default a few months ago to work on some changes to a project. However, now I want to make the branch I was working on the default branch. I want don't want to "merge" any changes from the new branch into default, I just want to override everything and replace default with the branch. Am I even going about this the right way? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a merge tool that does this.

First update to the default branch, then issue:

```
hg merge OTHERBRANCHNAME --tool internal:other
```

As always you should experiment in a clone so that you can restart if necessary.

Comment: This didn't quite work but it put me in the right direction. I was getting the following error:

hg merge: option --tool not recognized

I needed to set the HGMERGE environmental variable. Another option is the following:

hg --config ui.merge=internal:dump merge OTHERBRANCHNAME

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which version of Mercurial are you using? The `--tool` option to the merge command was introduced in Mercurial 1.7. If you're on an older version than that, you really ought to upgrade.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the info. My current version is 1.6.3 so it's looks like I will be upgrading now.